# insert values into table using concatenation and Varray

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

This is my code where METHODARGDATATYPE_VARRAY is a varray at 5th column in my table and first column has auto generated sequence concatenated with 't'.

```
 String arrayElements[] = { "Test3", "Test4" };
   ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor
                                        ("METHODARGDATATYPE_VARRAY", conn);
   ARRAY newArray = new ARRAY(desc, conn, arrayElements);

   String sql="insert into TestCaseIDDetails values (concat('t',TestCaseID_sequence.nextval),?,?,?,?)";
   PreparedStatement ps =
     conn.prepareStatement (sql);
   ps.setString(2,testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getClass_name()) ;
   ps.setString(3,testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getMethod_name()) ;
   ps.setString(4,testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getMethodReplacement()) ;
   ((OraclePreparedStatement)ps).setARRAY (5, newArray);

   ps.execute ();
```

Iam trying to execute this code but again Iam getting errors as follows:

```
      java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setARRAYInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5906)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setARRAY(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5898)
at implementation.TestCaseIDandDetailsDAOImpl.addTestCaseIDandDetails(TestCaseIDandDetailsDAOImpl.java:54)
at implementation.TestCaseIDandDetailsDAOImpl.main(TestCaseIDandDetailsDAOImpl.java:134)
```

my tablescripts are:

```
     CREATE or replace TYPE METHODARGDATATYPE_VARRAY AS VARRAY(20) OF varchar2(30);
     create table TestCaseIDDetails(
       testcaseID varchar2(20) primary key,
       classname varchar2(20) not null,
       methodname varchar2(20) not null,
       MethodReplacement char(2) check(MethodReplacement in ('y','n')),
       MethodArgDataType METHODARGDATATYPE_VARRAY);

     Create sequence TestCaseID_sequence minvalue 1 start with 1 increment by 1 ;
```

Comment: but after these modifications I am getting error as bellow: ORA-12899: value too large for column "ER706221"."TESTCASEIDDETAILS"."METHODREPLACEMENT" (actual: 10, maximum: 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following

```
ps.setString(2,testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getClass_name()) ;
   ps.setString(3,testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getMethod_name()) ;
   ps.setString(4,testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getMethodReplacement()) ;
   ((OraclePreparedStatement)ps).setARRAY (5, newArray);
```

to

```
ps.setString(1,testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getClass_name()) ;
   ps.setString(2,testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getMethod_name()) ;
   ps.setString(3,testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getMethodReplacement()) ;
   ((OraclePreparedStatement)ps).setARRAY (4, newArray);
```

Comment: @NagaumadeviPalaparthy please dont change the question other wise my answer will be void. Keep the original question and post another question for your new problem.

Comment: sry I had put it back to original question

Comment: but after these modifications I am getting error as bellow:                   ORA-12899: value too large for column "ER706221"."TESTCASEIDDETAILS"."METHODREPLACEMENT" (actual: 10, maximum: 2)

Comment: @NagaumadeviPalaparthy earlier your error was different and this time your error is different. So this means this is a different question

Comment: yes its different question but i cant post until 3 hrs and i need to do it immediately can u help me please?/

Comment: @NagaumadeviPalaparthy ok I will help,please tell me in which line you are getting this error and what value you are passing

Answer (score 3):

The indexes should correspond to the indexes of the question mark placeholders in the prepared statement, *not* to the column numbers in the table. The index of the first question mark is 1, the second is 2, and so on. Your indexes are all off by one, should be 1 2 3 4 instead of 2 3 4 5.

Comment: but after these modifications I am getting error as bellow: ORA-12899: value too large for column "ER706221"."TESTCASEIDDETAILS"."METHODREPLACEMENT" (actual: 10, maximum: 2)

Comment: Verify the value of `testCaseIDandDetailsBean.getMethodReplacement()`. It seems the value is not what you expect: a string of length 10